# Glyphicons not showing up properly on some browsers?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I have two lines

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" style="color: rgba(255, 121, 121, 1);"></span>
```

The glyph icon on this line shows up on every browser.However, the next line

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span>
```

doesn't show the glyph icon on Internet explorer and Opera mini and maybe others(I did not test them on all). My question is how could first glyph icon be displayed and second not? Is there something special about glyphicon-envelope or it is just that something is wrong with my setup?I am using bootstrap 3.2.0.

Comment: Maybe it's something about your font size because on Bootstrap official web I can see whole icons from IE10 http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Comment: Opera Mini doesn't support custom fonts: http://caniuse.com/#feat=fontface